# Kernel headers fail to install due to unmet dependencies

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to change my kernel on Ubuntu 12.04, but I receive an error when trying to install headers & images. I've never changed a kernel before, so your help is greatly appreciated.

I used uname -r to check my kernel version, and it's currently on: 2.6.32-042stab084.26.

```
$root@zeus:/home/tyler# dpkg -i linux-headers-3.2.60-030260-virtual_3.2.60-030260.201406091035_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.2.60-030260-virtual.
(Reading database ... 26837 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.60-030260-virtual (from linux-headers-3.2.60-030260-virtual_3.2.60-030260.201406091035_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-3.2.60-030260-virtual:
 linux-headers-3.2.60-030260-virtual depends on linux-headers-3.2.60-030260; however:
  Package linux-headers-3.2.60-030260 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-headers-3.2.60-030260-virtual (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-3.2.60-030260-virtual
```

Comment: Have you tried installing linux-headers-3.2.60-030260?

Comment: Not yet, I'll try that now. Will post results here.